# Unable to create the cache directory

Tags: cache, server

> Unable to create the cache directory
>   (/path/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates//36).

I receive this on one live installation of Craft CMS.
This is 99% a server issue with permissions. I can't even login to the CP anymore.

My question tough: I don't cache anything on the site.
Does Craft still cache things even with `'cache' => false,` or are these two different cache levels?

Comment: It may be worth noting that `cache` isn't a valid configuration property—and that I've been lying to myself for an unknown amount of time thinking it was.

Comment: What?? I used that property everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Craft still has its runtime caches for compiling Twig templates (as seen in your example) and such. Craft's template and partial cache is separate from Twig's own template compilation, if I'm not mistaken.

If storing in local folders won't work, you can change the [cacheMethod](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) setting to use a store other than a local directory ('memcache', 'apc', etc.).